# Panningmode="Both" seems not to be working

Tags: wpf, touch, scrollviewer

I'm using a WPF Scrollviewer as it is described [HERE (MSDN example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode.aspx)

I have the panning mode set to "Both" (I have tried it with panningmode set to "VerticalOnly" too) but on touch gesture I still get my text selected. I can scroll the contents only by touching the scrolling itself.
Seems that "Panningmode" doesn't change anything. What can be wrong?

Here is my sample app (the really simple msdn example):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTouchScrollViewer.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TextBox Name="textBox1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
                 ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        Hello world 1 Hello world 2 Hello world 3 Hello world 4 Hello world 5
                  Hello world 6 Hello world 7 Hello world 8 Hello world 9 Hello world 10 
                  Hello world 11 Hello world 12 Hello world 13 Hello world 14 Hello world 15 
                  Hello world 16 Hello world 17 Hello world 18 Hello world 19 Hello world 20 
                  Hello world 21 Hello world 22 Hello world 23 Hello world 24 Hello world 25 
                  Hello world 26 Hello world 27 Hello world 28 Hello world 29 Hello world 30 
                  Hello world 31 Hello world 32 Hello world 33 Hello world 34 Hello world 35 
                  Hello world 36 Hello world 37 Hello world 38 Hello world 39 Hello world 40 
                  Hello world 41 Hello world 42 Hello world 43 Hello world 44 Hello world 45 
                  Hello world 46 Hello world 47 Hello world 48 Hello world 49 Hello world 50 
                  Hello world 51 Hello world 52 Hello world 53 Hello world 54 Hello world 55 
                  Hello world 56 Hello world 57 Hello world 58 Hello world 59 Hello world 60 
                  Hello world 61 Hello world 62 Hello world 63 Hello world 64 Hello world 65 
                  Hello world 66 Hello world 67 Hello world 68 Hello world 69 Hello world 70 
                  Hello world 71 Hello world 72 Hello world 73 Hello world 74 Hello world 75 
                  Hello world 76 Hello world 77 Hello world 78 Hello world 79 Hello world 80 
                  Hello world 81 Hello world 82 Hello world 83 Hello world 84 Hello world 85 
                  Hello world 86 Hello world 87 Hello world 88 Hello world 89 Hello world 90 
                  Hello world 91 Hello world 92 Hello world 93 Hello world 94 Hello world 95 
                  Hello world 96 Hello world 97 Hello world 98 Hello world 99 Hello world 100 
                  Hello world 101 Hello world 102 Hello world 103 Hello world 104 Hello world 105 
                  Hello world 106 Hello world 107 Hello world 108 Hello world 109 Hello world 110 
                  Hello world 111 Hello world 112 Hello world 113 Hello world 114 Hello world 115 
                  Hello world 116 Hello world 117 Hello world 118 Hello world 119 Hello world 120 
                  Hello world 121 Hello world 122 Hello world 123 Hello world 124 Hello world 125 
                  Hello world 126 Hello world 127 Hello world 128 Hello world 129 Hello world 130 
                  Hello world 131 Hello world 132 Hello world 133 Hello world 134 Hello world 135 
                  Hello world 136 Hello world 137 Hello world 138 Hello world 139 Hello world 140 
                  Hello world 141 Hello world 142 Hello world 143 Hello world 144 Hello world 145 
                  Hello world 146 Hello world 147 Hello world 148 Hello world 149 Hello world 150 
                  Hello world 151 Hello world 152 Hello world 153 Hello world 154 Hello world 155 
                  Hello world 156 Hello world 157 Hello world 158 Hello world 159 Hello world 160 
                  Hello world 161 Hello world 162 Hello world 163 Hello world 164 Hello world 165 
                  Hello world 166 Hello world 167 Hello world 168 Hello world 169 Hello world 170 
                  Hello world 171 Hello world 172 Hello world 173 Hello world 174 Hello world 175 
                  Hello world 176 Hello world 177 Hello world 178 Hello world 179 Hello world 180 
                  Hello world 181 Hello world 182 Hello world 183 Hello world 184 Hello world 185 
                  Hello world 186 Hello world 187 Hello world 188 Hello world 189 Hello world 190 
                  Hello world 191 Hello world 192 Hello world 193 Hello world 194 Hello world 195 
                  Hello world 196 Hello world 197 Hello world 198 Hello world 199 Hello world 200
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! And it's not the PanningMode problem.
I was running the application on the remote machine: compiled it on my side, then connected to the remote machine, copied the build and run the .exe (all from my remote desktop connection)
Should have run the .exe directly on the machine I was testing the touch gestures. In this case everything works fine.
But now I wonder why this happens? I mean - touch gestures not working properly when I run my app from the remote desktop.

Comment: does not work for me either. Maybe you need to enable tablet mode for panning to work.